# Does RPCproxy or PageLoader in GXT cache data?

Tags: java, rpc, gxt

I have been playing around with the paging grid example found on Sencha GXT v4 examples. I am just curious to the fact if each page of data that gets loaded is cached or would I have to manually write a caching system to save each page of data. I use GXT v3.1.1

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in that example the data is not being cached and it does not show a mechanism to do,  every time you click on the paging buttons it makes a request to your service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. While we are on topic, do you know of any guides I can follow that would help me implement it.

Comment: @SandMan actually I don't like the way how GXT manage the pagination,  it uses offset a lot.  What about this approach: http://zawoad.blogspot.com/2010/07/working-with-gxt-grid-add-remote.html

Comment: So I went through your blog and this is basically how I applied paging to my grid. Does this mean it supports caching ? Also for interest sake how would you have applied pagination ?

Comment: hi @SandMan that is not my blog, sorry! afaik they don't have a mechanism for caching and it is a workaround.  I don't know what rdbms you are using,  but it may be managed by the database (including the cache): http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way (that blog is not mine).